# How to delete an entity from AppEngine datastore that matching a query?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How does one delete an entity from datastore that matches a query ? Is there a way to delete some object that matches a simple query ? Like 'Delete all objects with date before now' Or may be delete all entities that has property email with value mail@mail.com ?

Please provide your answers in java, if it is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Java API doesn't provide delete all functionality. You need to iterate the results of the query and than delete all the entities.

```
AsyncDatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getAsyncDatastoreService();

// create query for your kind
Query query = new Query("Kind");

// we don't need anything else than the key
query.setKeysOnly();

// set the filter for date before now 
query.setFilter(
    new FilterPredicate(
        "date", 
        FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, 
        new Date()));

PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(query);

// asIterable is more efficient than asList
for (Entity en : pq.asIterable()) {
    // delete each entity
    ds.delete(en.getKey());
}
```

Comment: So from what I can I am forced to do 2 calls to Datastore one to fetch the keys of the entities that matches the query the second one to delete the entities providing there keys ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. There is no way how to do it in one call.